# How to receive only value from the last request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In VueJS, I have handler of an input field changes, as below:

```
inputHandler(url, params){                    
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    ...
    ...
  });
  p.then(res => this.reactiveProperty = res);
}
```

So, I gain response and put it into a reactive variable. I send requests at order 1, 2, 3, 4, but receive responses in order 4, 1, 3, 2 (for example).

This is a reason, that the variable gets incorrect value. How could avoid it?

Comment: How is `inputHandler` called? You appear to have overlapping requests. Do you want the previous request's response values if you start a new request, or do you want to throw them away? Do you want to wait to start the next request until after the previous has finished? Or let them overlap but then process them in the same order they were started? Or...?

Comment: Side note: I urge you to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. Just beware of the footgun in the API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: I have form. One of the fields is v-model. Every time, when I type something there,  inputHandler is called. Only the latest response has some price, all other aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async, await. It will wait the first promise then gets to the second, second then third...etc. Also like @T.J. Crowder said, you should use the fetch api instead.